# javascript object initialization {key:val, string}

Tags: javascript, object, properties

I need to create an object which has a constant first key property. and the rest are dynamic (comes from db)
my solution is..
lets say like this:

```
var bar="bar"; //comes from db;
var myProperties="trick":"treat","man":"woman"; // comes from db
var obj = {"foo":bar, myProperties}
```

but i had an error. and i am not sure how to deal with this requirement.

anyone? alternative solution?

Answer (score 1):

You should merge the properties:

```
 function merge_options(obj1,obj2){
    var obj3 = {};
    for (var attrname in obj1) { obj3[attrname] = obj1[attrname]; }
    for (var attrname in obj2) { obj3[attrname] = obj2[attrname]; }
    return obj3;
 }

 var bar="bar"; //comes from db;
 var myProperties={trick:"treat",man:"woman"}; // comes from db
 var obj = merge_options({"foo":bar}, myProperties);
```

Or simpler create the object and set the foo property:

```
var obj={trick:"treat",man:"woman"};
obj.foo=bar;
```

Answer (score 0):

var object = new Object();
    var obj = {"foo":bar}

```
var myProperties="trick":"treat","man":"woman"; // comes from db

var object = myProperties.slipt(",");

for(var i=0; i < object.length ; i++){
    var item = object[i];

    obj.push(item);
}

// obj = {"foo":bar, "trick": treat, "man": woman} 

return obj;
```